# listview scroll horizontally

Tags: android, listview, horizontalscrollview

Is there anyway to make my listview scroll horizontally.
Now me implemented it using Horizontal scroll view. But i think it will not be good if there is many items
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView does not support scrolling horizontally, though [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) does.

Answer (score 0):

ya it can possible by wraping your all list item item in linearlayout and than setting scrollview horizontal..